# Ruby NameError: undefined local variable or method `r' for

Tags: ruby, macos, exception, nameerror

I've got this code within certain Class, and BTW this is plain ruby with test/unit, no Rails involved:

```
 10  %w[["y",true],["n",false]].each do |r, state|  
 11   def must_continue_to_ask_for_input_until_given_yes_or_no
 12
 13     provide_input(r)
 14 
 15     assert_equal state, @questioner.ask(@question)
 16   end
 17 end
```

upon running it with *!ruby %* from *vim* editor, I get this error:

```
  Line 13, NameError: undefined local variable or method `r' for #<QuestionerTest:0x007fe931981fd0>
```

*QuestionerTest* is my class and its derived from

```
Class QuestionerTest <Test::Unit::TestCase
```

Environment:

```
Ruby 2.2.1 on MACOSX Mavericks
No rails involved
test/unit involved
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you define a method like that, you are overriding each time, and, each time it will be defined the same. This is because the 'def method' is like a delayed execution -- when it's called the ruby method won't "see" the r and state as being in scope.

Also, the "%w" construct expects a series of strings to be converted into an array, so is possibly not doing what you think:

```
%w[one two three] == ["one", "two", "three"]

%w[["y",true],["n",false]].first
  => "[\"y\",true],[\"n\",false]"

%w[["y",true],["n",false]].first.class
  => String
```

If you want to generate multiple methods while capturing the surrounding vars, you can do something like this:

```
irb(main):043:0> [1,2,3].each do |r|
irb(main):044:1* define_method(:"foo#{r}") { |a| puts a, r }
irb(main):045:1> end
=> [1, 2, 3]

irb(main):046:0> foo1("hi")
hi
1
=> nil

irb(main):047:0> foo2("bye")
bye
2
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want thank adzdavies for taking the time of answering my silly question. Now based on his answer this is the code I wrote to fix it:

```
def must_continue_to_ask_for_input_until_given_yes_or_no
 [["y",true],["n",false]].each do |r, state|  
  %w[Note Yesterday axyesq].each do |mu|
    expect_output @question
    provide_input(mu)
    expect_output("I don't understand")
  end
  expect_output @question
  provide_input(r)

  assert_equal state, @questioner.ask(@question)
end
```

end

Thanks again and let's Ruby!